# Can't write data into database firebase firestore

Tags: android, google-cloud-firestore

I manage to insert the data to authentication, but could not insert to database:

**Code**:

```
fullname = findViewById(R.id.Ifullname);
        password = findViewById(R.id.Ipassword);
        email = findViewById(R.id.Iemail);
        RegisterBtn = findViewById(R.id.button);
        fAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        fStore = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
        loginBtn = findViewById(R.id.LoginBtn);
RegisterBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v){
                String FullName = fullname.getText().toString().trim();
                String Password = password.getText().toString().trim();
                String Email = email.getText().toString().trim();
fAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(Email, Password).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>(){
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task){
                        if(task.isSuccessful()){
                            Toast.makeText(Register.this, "User Created.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            UserID = fAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
                            DocumentReference documentReference = fStore.collection("users").document(UserID);
                            Map<String,Object> user = new HashMap<>();
                            user.put("FName", fullname);
                            user.put("Email",email);
                            user.put("Password",password);
//problem seems to be this line  
documentReference.set(user).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                                @Override
                                public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
                                    Log.d(TAG, "onSuccess: user Profile is created");
                                }

                            }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                                    Log.d(TAG, "onFailure:"+e.toString());

                                }
                            });
```

**Error**:

> E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main Process:
>   com.example.budgetingapp, PID: 11507 java.lang.RuntimeException: Found
>   conflicting getters for name getText on class
>   androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatEditText at
>   com.google.firebase.firestore.util.CustomClassMapper$BeanMapper.(com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore@@21.4.1:629)
>               at com.google.firebase.firestore.util.CustomClassMapper.loadOrCreateBeanMapperForClass(com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore@@21.4.1:377)
>               at com.google.firebase.firestore.util.CustomClassMapper.serialize(com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore@@21.4.1:177)
>               at com.google.firebase.firestore.util.CustomClassMapper.serialize(com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore@@21.4.1:140)
>               at com.google.firebase.firestore.util.CustomClassMapper.serialize(com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore@@21.4.1:104)
>               at com.google.firebase.firestore.util.CustomClassMapper.convertToPlainJavaTypes(com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore@@21.4.1:78)
>               at com.google.firebase.firestore.UserDataReader.convertAndParseDocumentData(com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore@@21.4.1:231)
>               at com.google.firebase.firestore.UserDataReader.parseSetData(com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore@@21.4.1:75)
>               at com.google.firebase.firestore.DocumentReference.set(com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore@@21.4.1:166)
>               at com.google.firebase.firestore.DocumentReference.set(com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore@@21.4.1:146)
>               **at com.example.budgetingapp.Register$1$1.onComplete(Register.java:95)**
>               at com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzj.run(Unknown Source:4)
>               at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
>               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
>               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
>               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)
>               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>               at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
>               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short, you are trying to add the TextField's themselves to your database, not the strings you created.

```
String FullName = fullname.getText().toString().trim();
String Password = password.getText().toString().trim();
String Email = email.getText().toString().trim();
/* ... */
user.put("FName", fullname);
user.put("Email",email);
user.put("Password",password);
```

---

I recommend adopting some naming conventions to prevent this. I personally recommend `<short-object-type><variable-name>` written in `camelCase`.

```
Button     #button   -> #btnRegister
Button     #LoginBtn -> #btnLogin
TextField  #fullname -> #txtFullName
TextField  #email    -> #txtEmail
TextField  #password -> #txtPwd
```

Sometimes it may also be useful to distinguish private object-level variables from local variables, conventionally by adding an `m` (for my) at the start of the name:

```
mBtnRegister.setOnClickListener(...);
Button btnScripted = new Button(...);
```

You should name variables in `camelCase` (or `UPPER_SNAKE_CASE` for constants) and not in `PascalCase` so they aren't misidentified as classes, interfaces, etc. You can actually see this in action by looking at the syntax highlighting of StackOverflow's code blocks.

---

```
String fullname = txtFullName.getText().toString().trim();
String password = txtPwd.getText().toString().trim();
String email = txtEmail.getText().toString().trim();
/* ... */
user.put("fname", fullname);
user.put("email", email);
// do not store passwords!
```

Comment: then how should I store my password? In authentication only instead of user database?

Comment: Firebase Authentication will securely hash and then store the password hash for you. Passwords should never be stored in databases. In the cases where you log in to services on behalf of a user, you should be using OAuth or some other form of access token instead.

Comment: but i do retrieve the id of my textview and put in "fullname". So, in my case ur txtFullName is my fullname. Or did I understand u wrongly?

Comment: so in other word i can still retrieve my password in case if i want to change it without me storing it manually?

Comment: When changing passwords, you must have re-logged in within the past few minutes and then you can call the [`updatePassword()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/auth/FirebaseUser#updatePassword(java.lang.String)) method. If a user doesn't remember their password, they can use the [`sendPasswordResetEmail()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/auth/FirebaseAuth#sendPasswordResetEmail(java.lang.String,%20com.google.firebase.auth.ActionCodeSettings)) method.

Comment: thanks it was my mistake. I didnt notice I put the string of the id of textview. It works!